# Setting default value in bootstrap datetimepicker results in NaN on popup

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am working on a project using Ruby + the Bootstrap framework, including the Bootstrap datetimepicker plugin.

I have a field in my form as thus:

```
<div class='datetimepicker-input input-group' id='logged_at'>
    <input class='form-control' data-format='DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A' name='logged_at' type='text' value='27/06/2014 05:08 PM'>
        <span class='input-group-addon'>
            <i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>
        </span>
    </input>
</div>
```

As you can see, I want my datetimepicker to use the `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A` formatting, however, when I enter a default date and time in the `value` attribute of the `<INPUT>` tag when generating the form, and then click on the calendar icon to pop up the picker, the picker window just gives me `NaN` in the heading and won't let me select a date or a time.

If however, I leave the `value` attribute blank when generating the form, the popup works just fine.

I have also noticed that if I type over the default date in the field, and swap the month and day around, i.e. as`MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A`,the popup works fine, i.e. the calendar defaults to the right day, however when I choose a date, it ***displays*** in the input field as `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A`.

I am wondering if there is another way I have to set the default date/time in the field?  Simply populating the `value` attribute seems to be confusing the plugin, as it appears to be wanting the initial date in mm/dd/yyyy..., but then happy to show it as dd/mm/yyyy... afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have figured this one out.  It appears to be related to `moment.js` which `bootstrap-datetimepicker` relies on for date parsing.

Without messing around with the language options, there was a line in **bootstrap-datetimepicker.js** (line 222) which had to be changed from:

```
if (dateStr) picker.date = moment(dateStr);
```

to

```
if (dateStr) picker.date = moment(dateStr, picker.format);
```

Basically we had to use the `picker.format` as the second parameter to force **mention** to parse the entered date using the supplied format that we had in the INPUT field.